# respond.js IE run script before rendering page

Tags: css, rendering, media-queries

I am using respond.js to add media query functionality to my web app. It works in IE8, but the  page renders differently for an initial second while respond.js runs and corrects the look of the page.

The script and css are run in the page .

```
<head>
...
    <link href="master.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="respond.min.js" />
...
</head>
```

Is there a way to get respond.js to run before the page renders?

Comment: no, how should the script manipulate the dom, before the dom is loaded

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate it after it is loaded, but before it gets displayed?

Comment: As far as I know not, but there might be some possibility that I haven't heard of